# Informatica XML - Skip Default Namespace

Tags: xml, xsd, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a XML created through Informatica XML Target which is created based on XSD

the elements and attributes are getting created without qualified Namespace since there is no qualified namespace in the xsd

Question, How can I skip the Default Namespace placed in XML file in RootElement Section When creating XML file 
This is the XML getting created

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
< RootElement xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-Instance >
 .
 .
<\RootElememnt>
```

Expected is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
< RootElement>
 .
 .
<\RootElememnt>
```

Kindly help me , Is there any solution or Do I request Target System to ignore Default Namespace, Currently the file is getting loaded when I remove that Default NS Line

Curious thing is, When I try to create sample XML file XML Editor and I am not seeing that content

I tried to check in or check out the no name space option in XML Editor - Informatica

Answer (score 2):

Your actual and expected XML are equivalent (for as much as you've shown us).  `RootElement` in both cases is in no namespace.

Your actual XML does not have a default namespace; it has a namespace prefix declaration.  If it had a default namespace of, say, `http://www.example.com/something` it would instead look like this:

```
<RootElement xmlns="http://www.example.com/something">
```

An unused namespace prefix declaration is innocuous.

Comment: Thanks for your post. As you said the unused namespace should be harmless. I m working with xml parser application to sort out this .

Comment: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.